# Are there other "elemental based" Chakra modes aside from Lightning

Tags: naruto, boruto

Just like the way the 3rd and 4th Raikage's were able to encase their entire bodies in their lightning release, forming the lightning release chakra mode. Is it also possible for other Ninja's to encase themselves in their elements.

What I mean by this is  (for example: a ninja with fire release, forming some kind of fire chakra mode by encasing the entire body with the fire release). This question is specific to the average skilled ninja (and is not including jinchuuriki's or Kekkai genkai users).

Comment: I don't think there is other element chakra mode besides lightning. The point of lightning chakra mode is to enhance the user's speed and reaction using lightning current or things like that. Now, let's say fire chakra mode. What does it enhance? The user's ... body heat?

Comment: Like it could be for defense. So that no one attacks you recklessly.

Comment: @Albert there is uchiha fire realese:- flame formation used by Obito, which can be used as defense against attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Earth Release: Earth Spear](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Release%3A_Earth_Spear) (Doton: Domu) which was used by Kakuzu could be seen as an earth variant.

> The user flows earth-natured chakra through all or parts of their body, causing it to become noticeably darker, all while increasing their defensive power to become as hard as diamond. As such, this allows the user to easily be able to withstand most attacks with little to no damage, with the exception of Lightning Release ninjutsu. Furthermore, the destructive power of physical attacks is increased, making this a great all-purpose technique.